# Compile Flags for Eclipse/Android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-optimization

So im trying to figure out how i can setup compile flags in Eclipse so when im developing my Android applications i can make a specific build. Example i have a WebView based application and i want to be able to build a QA version which will have a different URL `web.loadUrl("http://www.com");` I really don't want to have 2 projects QA and Release. I've been researching a way of bascially automizing this process. I dont want to have to go change the URL in the code each time before compiling and testing the application.

Comment: Did you get any help from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Make the url string configurable, for example via properties file, which you can easily access with the help of java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Ensure you do not need to recompile the application if you want to change the URL.

```
Properties applicationConfiguration = new Properties();
applicationConfiguration.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
String url = applicationConfiguration.getProperty("my.url", "http://defaulurl.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

In `SDK Tools, Revision 17 (March 2012)`:

- Added a feature that allows you to run some code only in debug mode. Builds now generate a class called BuildConfig containing a DEBUG constant that is automatically set according to your build type. You can check the (BuildConfig.DEBUG) constant in your code to run debug-only functions.

I find that the easiest way to accomplish what you want, is by checking the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` boolean.

The **DEBUG** boolean is always `true when developing`, only when you export a signed or unsigned apk, is it set to `false`. You can use it as:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { // Developing
    myURL = "http://www.bing.com";
}

// Or the other way around:

if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) { // Released (signed app)
    myURL = "http://www.google.com";
}
```